# Regex that captures variations of a capture group 0 or more times

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Trying to understand how to come up with a regex that allows a capture group containing variations to match all of its variations found in a string.

Example of the string as follows:

`/sometexthere/moretexthere?type=1234&data=56357782&noextract=6532`

Goal is to return `1234` and `56357782` but not `6532` using a pattern similar to the following, which is how far I was able to get:

`/sometexthere/moretexthere\?(?:&?(?:type|data|reason)=([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)*)+`

Another example string would be

`/sometexthere/moretexthere?data=56357782&noextract=6532&type=1234`

And would return `56357782` and `1234` but not `6532`

And another example

`/sometexthere/moretexthere?reason=1234`

And would return `1234`

The goal is to return the value that is part of the `(type|data|reason)` variations, so whenever there is a type, data, or reason - regardless of their order - in the string it will return the value that is in front of each one of them, not just the first/last match it finds.

Unfortunately the best regex I could come up with, exemplified above, is only returning the single last match of the string and not including any other matches before.

Don't know if it can have any relevance, but this is meant to be used in Android Java/Kotlin.

Comment: May sound silly but have you tried a global search `(?:type|data|reason)=(\d+)` Or even `(?:(?<=type=)|(?<=data=)|(?<=reason=))\d+`

Comment: @sln that is similar to lemon's first suggestion, but I have a requirement of keeping the initial string in the regex `/sometexthere/moretexthere?`. unless you can improve on his answer and suggest a regex with an expression that is only in front of `/sometexthere/moretexthere?` , like the one I came up with in my question. if I am not being clear, I man a regex with the first part of the text without any expression - just literal text, and the right side of it only containing expression(s)

Comment: if _`a requirement of keeping the initial string in the regex`_ then you're doing it the wrong way as seen here https://regex101.com/r/mlNDrf/1 .  In fact, the only way this can be done is using the `\G` anchor https://regex101.com/r/hGacBg/1 . And forget about using lookbehinds to only match _digits_ in the group[0], not even possible. The best you can do is to only capture the digits. In my example I also captured the type. I give this a term called _`regex span`_ It's unavoidable. If you want more explanation, ask, but I think you get the point.

Comment: @sln it wouldn't be only to match digits. Although in the examples I used only digits, the capture group is actually `([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)` so alphanumeric with colon, percentage, and minus sign. As I understand from your explanation then it would be better to just focus on the part after the static string I mentioned with a regex like the one you suggested. Issue with that is it would be part of validating a specific string that starts with that initial part, that's why I want to keep it in the regex. It's ok if what I want is not possible exactly, it's just a limitation of regex.

Comment: I think if you had clicked the links and examined the regexs in the tester, as you were reading my comment you would understand. But you didn't which seems evident. The regex you think works is just an initial _Group_ of alternations matching  `garbage?` or `&`,  preceding another _Group_ of alternations `type` or `data` or `reason` followed by some characters in a class. I assume your definition of static text means what, a text literal must exist before any of these groups can match ? Because `but I have a requirement of keeping the initial string` is _OPTIONAL_ in the regex you think works.

Comment: And fwiw, regex has no _limitation_ for what you need it for using the Java 8 engine. There is no need for assertions to isolate what you would like to keep, that's what capture groups  are for.

Comment: @sln I did click them at the time I replied, I understood I can't make it work just with a plain literal suffix like I hoped for, you even explained that was not possible. Doing the other way (your second link) ends up being the same as the other user's answer, and by that I mean it puts a regex at the suffix string thus going back to the same point you explained earlier. I did not ignore your examples, and I am sorry if it looked that way.

Comment: And if I am still being kinda confusing by what I was trying to say, I mean a plain suffix with no regex, just literally `/sometexthere/moretexthere?` with absolutely no regex operators anywhere in that suffix, followed by whichever regex could work for my purpose. You explained it very well: `In fact, the only way this can be done is using the \G anchor`

Comment: I believe at that point, since I can't make it happen exactly how I wanted, I would be better off checking if the string starts first with that suffix, and then do a match of the rest as a separate operation using the examples you and the other user provided.

Comment: The general reality of regex's is that running separate ones means they are disconnected and are not related to each other in space-time. Its like a Picasso vs a da Vinci. One does not flow from the other, there is a discontinuity, it's the kind of logic that software engineers working for SpaceX use.. why they all crash. Using the `\G` anchor insures the literal text exists before the other variables are matched. Continuous, one flows from the other. https://regex101.com/r/YfQWBC/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/G4jhCD/1, both capture Group 1, both are natural.

Comment: Note that since `\G` is a continuous match, the text between the text to be matched can be _validated_ to conform to the allowed characters. Note that SO has hundreds and hundreds examples of usage of the `\G` anchor. Try to look at those.

Comment: I've been appreciating all the knowledge you've been teaching me, and there is a lot of new stuff about regular expressions I didn't know about before - which I will definitely employ down the road now. Unfortunately for this specific case it doesn't work for me, I found that I was trying to over-simplify something that was in its foundation over-complicated. This exchange with you and the other user allowed me to understand that and work on a better strategy for what I was working with. I'm still using the regex I learned, but in a far more effective way now thanks to all of your help!

Comment: Keep up the good effort. Please do _not_ be intimidated by regex. Keep trying. Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance that your string will be located after one of the three keywords "type", "data" or "reason", you can directly use them with lookarounds to catch your required numbers.

```
(?<=(?:/sometexthere/moretexthere\?|&)\b(?:type|data|reason)\b=)([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)
```

Regex Explanation:

- `(?<=(?:/sometexthere/moretexthere\?|&)\b(?:type|data|reason)\b=)`:  lookaround

  - `(?:/sometexthere/moretexthere\?|&)`: non-capturing group with your path or "&"
  - `\b`: word boundary
  - `(?:type|data|reason)`: non-capturing group with one of the three words
  - `\b`: word boundary
  - `=`: "equals" sign
- `([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)`: your match

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/0bsdzk/1).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use a plain word boundary or any string, I need the regex to also match that start of the string `/sometexthere/moretexthere` as well as explicitly state what kind of values/characters the values can be `([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)` and I am not able to do that with your example, I tried replacing `\b` and `\d+` respectively but failed.

Comment: Have you tried the updated regex?

Comment: I did after I replied, did not see the edit in time, but there is still the digits left - it's not just digits, it's a group of possible characters `([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)` although I know I used only numbers in my examples, it can contain more than numbers. Also thanks for explaining each step of your suggestion, it really helps.

Comment: Seems like just replacing `\d+` with `([0-9a-z:.%\-]+)` is enough, thanks! Could you update your answer with that change?